# Java Thread, how to release resource when thread is done

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java class which extends from `Thread` and for example I want to send message to a queue, but want to reuse `Producer` for each thread. Not close it until `Thread` is done.

```
public class Producer extends Thread {
    private final QueueProducer producer;

    public Producer() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        producer = new QueueProducer(props);
    }

    public void send(String message) {
        producer.send(message);
    }

    // close?
}
```

For this piece of code how can I call the close method?

Comment: You need to release all resources at the end of `run()` method since this is the method which is executed when thread is started

Comment: You could even create and scope the producer with a `try-with-resources` block inside of `run`.  And why is `send` public? Are other threads calling methods on this Thread instance? That could spell trouble.

Comment: So why isn’t the run method overridden here? and why wouldn’t you just close the thing you’re using at the end of the run method?

Comment: @Thilo sorry the `send` shouldn't be to public, this is only called inside of `run`. Can I reuse the same instance of `QueueProducer` if I limit the scope inside of `run`?

Answer (score 1):

If `QueueProducer` does not implement `Closeable` and does not provide method to close its resources, then you can't close it explicitly. Best way is by limiting its scope inside run method hence eligible for GC.

However if it does `AutoCloseable` or `Closeable`, then wrap `QueueProducer` with try-with-resources block to automatically close it after its usage.

```
public void run(){

    try(QueueProducer qp = producer){
        //do operation on qp
    }
}
```

Or make `Producer` to implement `Closeable`. In its overriden close method will close QueueProducer instead. For example:-

```
class Producer extends Closeable{

   private final QueueProducer qp;

   ....

   @Override
   public void close(){

      if(qp!=null){
         qp.close();
      }
   }
}
```

This is similar to `BufferedReader` whom its close method close its internal `Reader` object. Thus `QueueProducer` remain usable until client close `Producer` itself.

Comment: Resources such as database connections and some others should be closed explicitly. GC will not close them

Comment: Yes and most of them are either `AutoCloseable` or provided with sort of close() method. If forget to close, it will be catastrophic as resources such socket, connection, etc2 will be remained occupied.

Comment: Yes, the `QueueProducer` implements `AutoCloseable`. But the thing is I don't want to call `close` method each time after call `send`. I will only want to create one instance of `QueueProducer`. If using `try-with-resources` I assume the `close` is called every time?

Comment: @ttt,  retrofit `Producer` to implement `Closeable`. In its overriden `close` method close `QueueProducer` instead. This is similar to `BufferedReader` whom its close method close its internal `Reader` state. Thus `QueueProducer` remain usable until client close `QueueProducer`.

Comment: @AwanBiru If it's a running web app? Do I have to do the same?